# vector<unique_ptr<A> > using initialization list

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, containers, unique-ptr

I have encountered an error: **call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'std::__1::unique_ptr >'** when compile code similar to below using
**c++ -std=c++14 unique_ptr_vector.cpp -o main**

Here is a simplified version:

header file 'my_header.h':

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class A{
public:
    A() : n(0) {}
    A(int val) : n(val) {} 
    A(const A &rhs): n(rhs.n) {}
    A(A &&rhs) : n(std::move(rhs.n)) {}
    A& operator=(const A &rhs) { n = rhs.n; return *this; }
    A& operator=(A &&rhs) { n = std::move(rhs.n); return *this; }
    ~A() {}

    void print() const { std::cout << "class A: " << n << std::endl; }
private:
    int n;
};

namespace {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>> vecA = {
        std::make_unique<A>(1),
        std::make_unique<A>(2),
        std::make_unique<A>(3),
        std::make_unique<A>(4)
    };
}
```

And my src file `unique_ptr_vector.cpp`:

```
#include "my_header.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    for(const auto &ptrA : vecA){
        ptrA->print();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Do I really need to use `push_back(std::make_unique<A>(<some_number>))` individually for each component,
Or what would be a preferred way to populate a container in a header? Or is this a bad idea in general?

I have seen problems around like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39724272/error-call-to-implicitly-deleted-copy-constructor-of-std-1unique-ptra-s), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40878530/unique-ptr-with-vector-error-call-to-implicitly-deleted-copy-constructor-of-xx), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40878530/unique-ptr-with-vector-error-call-to-implicitly-deleted-copy-constructor-of-xx).

I know now Initialization list seems impossible. but what do people normally do with `container<unique_ptr>`. Should I just simply avoid initialize that in a header...

Comment: The problem is not the deleter, but the fact that `std::unique_ptr` is move-only and the `std::initialiser_list` constructor copies the elements. I'm afraid you're stuck with calling `.push_back`.

Comment: I was thinking of this possibility because initialize a container<unique_ptr> in a header would be easier for me. Otherwise, I'll have to define another function to populate the container. This is ok, I have no issue with push_back(), but I thought there would be a more concise way.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Initialization lists are wrappers around `const` arrays.

`unique_ptr`s that are `const` cannot be moved-from.

We can hack around this (in a perfectly legal way) like this:

```
template<class T>
struct movable_il {
  mutable T t;
  operator T() const&& { return std::move(t); }
  movable_il( T&& in ): t(std::move(in)) {}
};

template<class T, class A=std::allocator<T>>
std::vector<T,A> vector_from_il( std::initializer_list< movable_il<T> > il ) {
  std::vector<T,A> r( std::make_move_iterator(il.begin()), std::make_move_iterator(il.end()) );
  return r;
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0a4aaf0a85b14571).

Use:

```
auto v = vector_from_il< std::unique_ptr<int> >({
  std::make_unique<int>(7), 
  std::make_unique<int>(3)
});
```

If you want to know *why* initializer lists reference const data, you'll have to track down and read committee minutes or ask someone who was there.  I'd guess it is about the principle of least surprise and/or people with bugaboos about mutable data and view types (such as the renaming of `array_view` to `span`).

If you want more than just vectors:

```
template<class C, class T=typename C::value_type>
C container_from_il( std::initializer_list< movable_il<T> > il ) {
  C r( std::make_move_iterator(il.begin()), std::make_move_iterator(il.end()) );
  return r;
}
```

which still needs massaging to work right with associative containers as we also want to move the key.

```
template<class VT>
struct fix_vt {
  using type=VT;
};
template<class VT>
using fix_vt_t = typename fix_vt<VT>::type;
template<class VT>
struct fix_vt<const VT>:fix_vt<VT>{};
template<class K, class V>
struct fix_vt<std::pair<K,V>>{
  using type=std::pair<
    typename std::remove_cv<K>::type,
    typename std::remove_cv<V>::type
  >;
};

template<class C, class T=fix_vt_t<typename C::value_type>>
C container_from_il( std::initializer_list< movable_il<T> > il ) {
  C r( std::make_move_iterator(il.begin()), std::make_move_iterator(il.end()) );
  return r;
}
```

Comment: Just bumped into this, brilliant! Any hints for maps? What I would need is exactly the exercise left to the reader :-D ("which still needs massaging to work right with associative containers as we also want to move the key").

Comment: @SergioLosilla In deducinG `T`, you need to remove the `const` from the key part of the `std::pair<const K, V>` that is `std::map<K,V>::value_type` so move-from works (efficiently)

Comment: I am learning a lot here, thanks :-)

If you don't mind I will keep asking. With

`using iptr = std::unique_ptr<int>;`

The following works

`vector_from_il<iptr>({iptr{new int{3}}, iptr{new int{5}}});`

But the following doesn't, because template deduction fails (I am using g++ 8.1.1 with -std=c++14):

`container_from_il<std::vector<iptr>>({iptr{new int{6}}, iptr{new int{9}}});`

Comment: I added a question to follow up on this, so I can pester other people as well :-)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50629016/initializing-container-of-unique-ptrs-using-initialization-list-continued

Comment: I added a follow up question for a related case involving polymorphism, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72450903/vectorunique-ptrbase-using-initialization-list-of-derived