# Initializing container of unique_ptr's using initialization list, continued

Tags: c++

I would want to initialize `std::vector`'s and `std::map`'s of `std::unique_ptr<T>`'s. In my case, `T` is fixed. In this example I assume that `T`=`int`, although in reality it is a base class from which a bunch of other classes are derived.

I have been studying the answer given in:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46771893/4875652

and I have not managed to get it working for the `std::map` case.

The following works:

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

struct movable_il {
  mutable iptr t;
  operator iptr() const&& { return std::move(t); }
  movable_il( iptr&& in ): t(std::move(in)) {}
};

std::vector<iptr> vector_from_il( std::initializer_list<movable_il> il ) {
  return std::vector<iptr>( std::make_move_iterator(il.begin()), std::make_move_iterator(il.end()) );
}

int main()
{
    auto lol = vector_from_il({iptr{new int{3}}});

   return 0;
}
```

However, the following does not:

```
#include <memory>
#include <map>
#include <utility>

using iptr = std::unique_ptr<int>;

struct movable_il {
  mutable std::pair<std::string, iptr> t;
  operator std::pair<std::string, iptr>() const&& { return std::move(t); }
  movable_il( std::pair<std::string, iptr>&& in ): t(std::move(in)) {}
};

std::map<std::string, iptr> container_from_il( std::initializer_list< movable_il> il ) {
  return std::map<std::string, iptr>( std::make_move_iterator(il.begin()), std::make_move_iterator(il.end()) );
}

int main()
{
    auto lol = container_from_il({std::pair<std::string, iptr>{"a", iptr{new int{3}}}});

   return 0;
}
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

The simplest working example I managed to get, that was as similar as possible to the original code, not using templates, is this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>

struct movable_pair {
  using first_type = std::string;
  using second_type = std::unique_ptr<int>;
  using pair_type = std::pair<const first_type, second_type>;
  first_type first;
  mutable second_type second;
  operator pair_type() const && { return {first, std::move(second)}; }
  movable_pair(pair_type &&in): first{in.first}, second{std::move(in.second)} {}
};

auto map_from_il(std::initializer_list<movable_pair> il) {
  return std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<int>>(std::make_move_iterator(il.begin()),
                                                     std::make_move_iterator(il.end()));
}

// Main function
int main() {
  using iptr = std::unique_ptr<int>;
  auto lol = map_from_il({{{"a", iptr{new int{3}}}}, {{"b", iptr{new int{2}}}}});

  // Small print-out to check we inserted the correct elements :)
  for (auto &l : lol) {
    std::cout << l.first << " " << *l.second << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Kudos to user Banan for the help, particularly figuring out the extra pair of curly braces needed.

Comment: Even if not enough, `std::map<std::string, iptr>::value_type` is `std::pair<const std::string, iptr>` (const Key).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem, as far as I see it, is that you need to make the `pair`'s movable. This is perfectly done by the `movable_il` class, but now you get into trouble trying to construct the `map` from these, as the `first` and `second` members are not defined for `movable_il`.

As you are anyways trying to construct the `map` from an iterator, I don't imagine you'll see any performance hit by doing the iteration yourself and inserting the elements manually. I've made a solution based on this. It's not the prettiest solution, but It'll do the job.

Furthermore I had some issues to get the compiler to deduce the correct type for `T` from the `pair` "initialization list", thus I made a small helper function `movable_pair` to create these, in which case the compiler has no problems.

```
#include <memory>
#include <map>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// Wrapper class to make type T "movable"
template<class T>
struct movable_il 
{
   mutable T t;
   operator T() const&& { return std::move(t); }
   movable_il( T&& in ): t(std::move(in)) {}

   T get() const { return std::move(t); }
};

// Some template magic to deduce the correct value_type 
// ( not really needed for this example as we are mostly interested in maps )
template<class VT>
struct fix_vt 
{
  using type = VT;
};

template<class VT>
using fix_vt_t = typename fix_vt<VT>::type;

template<class VT> struct fix_vt<const VT> :  fix_vt<VT>  {};

template<class K, class V>
struct fix_vt< std::pair<K,V> >
{
   using type = std::pair<
      typename std::remove_cv<K>::type,
      typename std::remove_cv<V>::type
   >;
};

// Create map from initializer list of movable T (pairs)
template<class C, class T = fix_vt_t<typename C::value_type> >
auto map_from_il(std::initializer_list< movable_il<T> > il)
{
   using map_type = C;
   auto map = map_type{};

   // Loop over il list and insert each element into the map
   for(auto&& entry : il)
   {
       map.insert(std::move(entry.get())); // We get the pair from the movable class and insert it by moving
   }

   return map;
}

// Helper function to create movable pair
template<class First, class Second>
auto movable_pair(First&& f, Second&& s)
{
   using pair_type = std::pair<First, Second>;
   return movable_il<pair_type>{ pair_type{ std::forward<First>(f), std::forward<Second>(s) } };
}

// Main function
int main()
{
   using iptr = std::unique_ptr<int>;
   using key_type   = std::string;
   using value_type = iptr;

   using map_type    = std::map<key_type, value_type>;

   auto lol = map_from_il<map_type>({ movable_pair("a", iptr{ new int {3} } ), movable_pair("b", iptr{ new int {2} }) });

   // Small print-out to check we inserted the correct elements :)
   for(auto& l : lol)
   {
      std::cout << l.first << " " << *l.second << std::endl;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Disclaimer: I have only tested this with GCC 8.1.0 (but I don't imagine any issues using other compilers).

**Update:** If you put in and extra set of `{` and `}` when passing the pairs to `map_from_il`, the code compiles without the use of the `movable_pair` helper function.

```
auto lol = map_from_il<map_type>({ { {"a", iptr{ new int {3} } } }, { {"b", iptr{ new int {2} } } } });
```

**Update 2:** If you add the following constructor to `movable_il`, the code also compiles without the extra `{` and `}`:

```
template<class... U>
movable_il( U&&... in): t{std::forward<U>(in)...} {}
```

With this you can write:

```
auto lol = map_from_il<map_type>({ {"a", iptr{ new int {3} } }, {"b", iptr{ new int {2} } } });
```