# How to get the first element in a std::set of pointers, where the pointer points to a specific value?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++17, smart-pointers, stdset

Say you have a C++ `std::set` of unique pointers e.g.

```
auto my_set = std::set<std::unique_ptr<std::string>> 
{ 
    std::make_unique<std::string>("monkey"),
    std::make_unique<std::string>("banana"),
    std::make_unique<std::string>("orange") 
};
```

Using the `std::find_if` function, how would you go about finding the first element within this set such that the pointer points to "`orange`"?

So far I have got:

```
auto food = "orange";
auto find_orange
   = std::find_if(my_set.begin(), my_set.end(), [&food](const auto& ptr) -> bool {
        return *(*ptr) == food;
    }
);
```

but this does not compile. Any ideas on what the issue is?

Also in these kinds of functions what exactly is `ptr`
i.e. the parameter in the predicate? Is it a pointer to each element of the container?

Comment: Why would you use unique pointers to strings?

Comment: Does it fail to compile because you've forgot a semicolon after "orange" on the first line?

Comment: no, the error is "indirection requires pointer operand"

Comment: @eerorika it's part of a specific thing I need to do, I know it's not the most usual thing

Comment: Isn't `ptr` already a `const std::unique_ptr<std::string> &`? It only needs 1 indirection.

Comment: `ptr` is `const std::unique_ptr<std::string> &`, `*ptr` is `const std::string &`, and `*(*ptr)` would dereference a string, typo?

Comment: Can you even make a `std::set<std::unique_ptr<std::string>>` like this: https://godbolt.org/z/3redfW  ??

Comment: apparently just *ptr == food is the fix

Comment: @JeJo [You can't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46737054/vectorunique-ptra-using-initialization-list).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question lacks a proper minimal reproducible example. When we make one MCVC: https://godbolt.org/z/bfYx39

The problem is coming from lambda return

```
return *(*ptr) == food;
```

as the `auto` there is  `std::unique_ptr<std::string>`. Therefore you need to just dereference once:

```
auto find_orange = std::find_if(my_set.begin(), my_set.end(),
      [&food](const auto& ptr) {
         return *ptr == food;
         //     ^^^^^^^^^^^^
      }
   );
```

you do not need to double dereferencing there.