# How to use std::find_if with a vector of unique pointers?

Tags: c++, algorithm, unique-ptr

How do you use algorithms like `std::find_if` with a vector of unique pointers? For instance:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>

class Integer {
public:
    explicit Integer(int i): i_(i){};

    int get() const{
        return i_;
    }

private:
    int i_;
};

using IntegerPtr = std::unique_ptr<Integer>;

int main() {
    IntegerPtr p1 = std::make_unique<Integer>(4);
    IntegerPtr p2 = std::make_unique<Integer>(5);
    IntegerPtr p3 = std::make_unique<Integer>(6);
    std::vector<IntegerPtr> vectorOfIntegerPointers({
        std::move(p1),
        std::move(p2),
        std::move(p3),
    });

    int i = 5;

    auto first_index_larger_than_i = std::find_if(vectorOfIntegerPointers.begin(), vectorOfIntegerPointers.end(), [&](IntegerPtr s) {
        return s->get() > i;
    });

    std::cout << first_index_larger_than_i.get() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Fails with

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:1881:31: error: call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'std::__1::unique_ptr<Integer, std::__1::default_delete<Integer> >'
            ::new((void*)__p) _Up(_VSTD::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
                              ^   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Oops, yes thank you.

Comment: @Galik I've tried that variation and I get the same error

Comment: By `std::move(p1)` you move unqiue_ptr into initializer list, but when ctor of vector taking initializer list is called, it tries to copy all unique_ptrs of list, which is not possible, because unique_ptr cannot be copied.

Comment: Aaah I see, so initializer lists cannot be used with `unique_ptr`s. Good to know. I have it working now, thanks to all your advice. Happy to accept an answer if you post one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 problems in the code both leading to an attempt to copy the non-copyable `unique_ptr`.

1. `unique_ptr` can't be passed to `vector(initializer_list)` constructor, because `initializer_list` wraps its elements as `const` objects, and a `const` object cannot be moved-from. So the move-constructor doesn't participate in overload resolution, leaving only the copy constructor as a candidate, which later fails to compile with the error you saw: "*call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor*".

   So you have to use another solution to construct `vector<unique_ptr>`, for example using `push_back`:

   ```
    std::vector<IntegerPtr> vectorOfIntegerPointers;
    vectorOfIntegerPointers.push_back(std::make_unique<Integer>(4));
    vectorOfIntegerPointers.push_back(std::make_unique<Integer>(5));
    vectorOfIntegerPointers.push_back(std::make_unique<Integer>(6));
   ```

   Or write a wrapper to hold `unique_ptr` as `mutable` members ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46771893/485343)).
2. `[&](IntegerPtr s) { ... }` used in `std::find_if` attempts to take instances of `unique_ptr` by-value. But `unique_ptr` is not copyable, hence the same error.

   A quick fix is to take them by-reference instead:

   `[&](IntegerPtr const& s) { ... }`