# Create std::list unique_ptr from variadic template

Tags: c++, c++14, variadic-templates

I try to create std::list from args, but when pass more than 0 params get an error "no matching function for call to 'make_unique'". I think that the mistake is that I pass all the arguments to make_unque at once, but I do not understand how to open the bundle 2 times.

```
template<class ...Args>
void do(Args&&... args)
{
    std::list<std::unique_ptr<Base>> obj(std::make_unique<Child>(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure you need `obj{std::make_unique<Child>(std::forward<Args>(args))...}`

Comment: @NathanOliver: but then the issue is with the fact that initializer_list has const element, and cannot be moved.

Comment: @Jarod42 Oh yeah, those pesky const elements.  Well that makes this a more complicated.

Comment: Looks like there is a hack here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46737054/vectorunique-ptra-using-initialization-list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Syntax would be:

```
template<class ...Args>
void do(Args&&... args)
{
    std::list<std::unique_ptr<Base>> obj{std::make_unique<Child>(std::forward<Args>(args))...};
}
```

but you cannot move elements from `std::initializer_list` (their element are `const`).

A possible workaround is to `emplace`:

```
template<class ...Args>
void do(Args&&... args)
{
    std::list<std::unique_ptr<Base>> obj;

#if 0 // C++17
    (obj.emplace(std::make_unique<Child>(std::forward<Args>(args)), ...);
#else // C++11 and C++14
    int dummy[] = {0, (obj.emplace(std::make_unique<Child>(std::forward<Args>(args)), 0)...};
    static_cast<void>(dummy); // avoid warning for unused variable.
#endif
}
```