# vector<unique_ptr<Base> > using initialization list of Derived

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I have a follow-up question to this one:

[vector<unique_ptr<A> > using initialization list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46737054/vectorunique-ptra-using-initialization-list)

I would like to achieve essentially the same goal as in the referenced question, but this time using polymorphic classes. That is, I would like to create a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>>` using an initialization list.

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
struct movable_il {
  mutable T t;
  operator T() const&& { return std::move(t); }
  movable_il( T&& in ): t(std::move(in)) {}
};

template<class T, class A=std::allocator<T>>
std::vector<T,A> vector_from_il( std::initializer_list< movable_il<T> > il ) {
  std::vector<T,A> r( std::make_move_iterator(il.begin()), std::make_move_iterator(il.end()) );
  return r;
}

// Example with class hierarchy
class Base
{
public:
  Base(int in) : x(in) {}
  virtual ~Base() = default;
  virtual void print() const = 0;
protected:
  int x;
};

class Derived1 : public Base
{
public:
  Derived1(int in) : Base(in) {}
  virtual ~Derived1() = default;
  virtual void print() const override { std::cout << "Derived1: " << x << std::endl; }
};

class Derived2 : public Base
{
public:
  Derived2(int in) : Base(in) {}
  virtual ~Derived2() = default;
  virtual void print() const override { std::cout << "Derived2: " << x << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{

  {
    auto v = vector_from_il< std::unique_ptr<Base> >({
      std::make_unique<Derived1>(7),
      std::make_unique<Derived2>(3)
    });

    for (const auto & val : v)
      val->print();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

the compiler (GCC 7.4.0 on Ubuntu 18) error message is:

```
template argument deduction/substitution failed:
cannot convert '{std::make_unique(_Args&& ...)
[with _Tp = Derived1;
 _Args = {int};
 typename std::_MakeUniq<_Tp>::__single_object = std::unique_ptr<Derived1, std::default_delete<Derived1> >](),
std::make_unique(_Args&& ...)
[with _Tp = Derived2;
 _Args = {int};
 typename std::_MakeUniq<_Tp>::__single_object = std::unique_ptr<Derived2, std::default_delete<Derived2> >]()}'
(type '<brace-enclosed initializer list>') to type 'std::initializer_list<movable_il<std::unique_ptr<Base> > >'
```

I assume the error is related to the fact that no conversions are taken into account during template argument deduction, so maybe this is just not possible to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding extra constructor

```
template <typename U>
movable_il(U&& in): t(std::forward<U>(in)) {}
```

fixes compilation.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/fz4YaThWc).